# How to convert default string character to original one in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to correct the file name which is written different from original language in Python 3.x.

File name is `HIB_GUNLUK_GERÃ‡EK_EVAPOTRANSPIRASYONLAR_MM_BOLU_GUN.csv`

But I want to see that as `HIB_GUNLUK_GERÇEK_EVAPOTRANSPIRASYONLAR_MM_BOLU_GUN.csv`.

Briefly my file name consists `Ã‡` instead of `Ç`. How can I fix that. Because I use for loop to see the files and file names are controlled with if statement. If I compare this it returns `False`:

```
>>HIB_GUNLUK_GERÃ‡EK_EVAPOTRANSPIRASYONLAR_MM_BOLU_GUN.csv == HIB_GUNLUK_GERÇEK_EVAPOTRANSPIRASYONLAR_MM_BOLU_GUN.csv
False
```

Comment: How many these special characters do you have in your language? You can use myString.replace('Ã‡', 'Ç') etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode from the incorrect Windows-1252 to get the original bytes back, then decode as the UTF-8 that it actually was:

```
>>> 'HIB_GUNLUK_GERÃ‡EK_EVAPOTRANSPIRASYONLAR_MM_BOLU_GUN.csv'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')
'HIB_GUNLUK_GERÇEK_EVAPOTRANSPIRASYONLAR_MM_BOLU_GUN.csv'
```

Comment: I think it is more generic. Appreciate